# can content attribute of meta element and style attribute contains line breaks?

Tags: html

is the following html code legal?

```
<meta name="keyword" content="
  keyword1,
  keyword2
  ">
```

and:

```
<div style="
  color: white;
  background: green;
  "></div>
```

Comment: http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following markup does indeed validate using the [validator.w3.org/check](http://validator.w3.org/check)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>asd</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="
    keyword1,
    keyword2
  ">
</head>
<body>
<div style="
  color: white;
  background: green;
  "></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However I would recommend against doing it. The reasons being:

- It is adding unnecessary characters to the document body, increasing the overall size of the webpage.
- It is bad practice.
- It's easier to read HTML as a whole if tags are limited to a single line. This is much nicer to read in my opinion:

  ```
  <meta name="keyword" content="keyword1, keyword2">
  ```

As for your styles, I suggest you use a separate CSS stylesheet for your styles so they are reusable and contained within a single area.

```
<div class="stylised"></div>
```

CSS

```
.stylised {
    color: white;
    background: green;
}
```

FYI, I needed to change the `name` attribute of your `<meta>` tag to `keywords` instead of `keyword` in order for it to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing engines would normally attempt to ignore those line breaks, but just to be safe, validate your HTML markup with the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/).